# Use total number of rows in selection in calculation with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I've been using `data.table` with `by=` arguments and the group count (`.N`) in order to create frequency tables.

For example:

```
patients = data.table(
  id = 1:10,
  gender = c("M", "F"),
  age = c(19, 7, 3, 13, 18, 12, 16, 15, 9, 4)
)

patients[, .(n = .N), by = gender]
```

Produces:

```
   gender n
1:      M 5
2:      F 5
```

This works very well, although I often also need to calculate the proportion, which I do as follows:

```
patients[, .(n = .N, p = .N / nrow(patients)), by = gender]
```

Giving:

```
   gender n   p
1:      M 5 0.5
2:      F 5 0.5
```

This, although a little clunky, works fine until I don't have `patients` around to work with, such as when subsetting, which results in this sort of construct:

```
patients[age > 12, .(n = .N, p = .N / nrow(patients[age > 12])), by = gender]
```

Which, with our sample data, gives:

```
   gender n   p
1:      M 3 0.6
2:      F 2 0.4
```

One solution I've noted is to precompute the subset:

```
teens = patients[age > 12]
teens[, .(n = .N, p = .N / nrow(teens)), by = gender]
```

Which produces identical output to the above.

However this is also suboptimal in that it requires explicit reference to `teens`. How best I go about this sort of calculation using `data.table` without explicit reference to the subset?

Comment: Please show some small reproducible example and expected output based on that.

Comment: @akrun There you go.

Comment: Maybe `patients[age > 12, .(n = .N), by = gender][,p:=n/sum(n)][]`.

Comment: Or `patients[age > 12, total:=.N][,.(n=.N, p=.N/total),by=gender]`

Comment: @Heroka Of the syntax I've seen so far I like this best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit unclear what "optimal" means for you. Comment options are fine, and here's one more:

```
patients[age > 12, {nrow = .N; .SD[, .(n = .N, p = .N/nrow), by = gender]}]
#   gender n   p
#1:      M 3 0.6
#2:      F 2 0.4
```

Comment: Please see updated question for clarification of 'optimal'. Your solution fits with the clarification.

Comment: I think perhaps I'm just not crazy about the syntax required to pull this off. Would be much nicer to have a `.ALL` or `.TOT`, or similar.